# как проверить выбор файла в input[file]

Tags: javascript

нужно что бы когда файл уже выбрали изменялся label, как проверять на выбор файла в js?

Answer (score 0):

У `input[file]` есть свойство `files` где хранятся все файлы, можете проверить его длину.

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <h1 id="title">Выберите файлы</h1>
   <input type="file" name="file" multiple>
</form>

<script>
  const form = document.forms[0];
  const file = form.file;
  const title = document.getElementById('title');
 
  file.addEventListener('change', event => {
    if (file.files.length > 0) {
        title.textContent = `Выбрано: ${file.files.length}`;
     }
  });
</script>
```